# SQL Server Execute Query Every Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to execute a query in the Management Studio every 3 seconds for monitoring/maintenance needs. I know I can define a job or use an external application. But I 'm looking for something much simpler. Something like the following pseudo:

```
DECLARE @Interval INT
SET @Interval = 3000 -- I'm expecting milliseconds
BEGINLOOP (@Interval)
    SELECT * FROM MyTransactions
ENDLOOP
```

I would like the output to refresh every 3 seconds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 12):

You could use WAITFOR in a loop. You would specify the interval time in the WAITFOR statement.

Something like this:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' -- Wait 5 seconds

   SELECT * FROM MyTransactions

   -- Break on some condition
END
```

Comment: That must be the answer. However, the output is not refreshing, it appends to the previous result. Can we avoid that?

Comment: You could insert those rows into a table (if the amount is ~small) and when needed somebody could query that table.

Comment: Try adding a GO after the Select statement. Not sure if this will force the ouptput, but it might. You could also send the output of the query to a temporary table and query the temporary table via another connection in SSMS.

Comment: GO is not allowed in the middle of a scope

Comment: My problem would be solved if the result window can be cleared using an SQL command!

Comment: Right, unfortunately, the query results will eventually display but what you're going to get is a whole slew of query result windows. I think probably your best bet is to write the results to a temp table and query that under a different connection.

Comment: Even if I write to a temp table, I will face the same problem when I will make my loop on that table.

Comment: Just write a shell script that is executed, outputting STDOUT to a file.  Then in another console, use `tail -f -n 100 <output.txt>` to monitor the output (you'll need tail from Cygwin, unfortunately).  You can loop in a Powershell or bat file on whatever interval you'd like.

Comment: If you want to see the output straight away use `RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/

Comment: To expand on @Nick.McDermaid 's addition, below format helped me monitor a query result recurring in an interval `WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' -- Wait 5 seconds
   declare @count int = 0;

   set @count = 
   (
        select count(*)
 from Table1 (nolock)
 where 
     Condition = 'NotExported'
 )
 RAISERROR(@count, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
END` and the count variable could be watched through the "Messages" window every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna share other possibility. Avoiding wait for the whole the query ends.

```
DECLARE @initialTime AS datetime = getdate()
    , @duration AS INT = 15 --in seconds
    , @interval AS INT = 3 --in seconds
    , @amountOfCycles AS INT = 0

DECLARE @maxTime as datetime = dateadd(second,@duration,@initialTime)

WHILE @initialTime <= @maxTime
BEGIN
    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    SET @amountOfCycles += 1

    IF DATEDIFF(second,@initialTime,GETDATE()) >= @interval 
    BEGIN 
        print 'do something'
        SET @initialTime = GETDATE()
    END
    
END

PRINT '@amountOfCycles: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@amountOfCycles),'')
```

I omitted the `WAITFOR DELAY` command (inside `WHILE`). However, I noticed the number of cycles for my example of 15 seconds doing the process, it took almost 2 millions times in the cycle... too much memory.

```
@amountOfCycles: 1798079
```

It should be taken into account, but it is another possibility.

However, for now, it solves @yazanpro's doubt

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE (@i <= 60)
 BEGIN
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

       /*Your Script*/

 SET  @i = @i + 1;
END 
print 'completed'
```

Comment: elaborate your answer